# Adjusting file structure resulted in Github file size limit

Tags: reactjs, git, github, create-react-app

I have a react app which was originally bootstrapped using create-react-app in my App directory as follows:

```
App
|-- build
|-- node_modules
|-- etc...
```

I've adjusted the file structure to now look like the following and made a new commit:

```
 App
 |-- client
     |-- build
     |-- node_modules
     |-- etc...
 |-- server
```

I moved all my create-react-app contents into a new /client directory inside that original project. Nothing is wrong with my app. It's working as intended. My issue is that when I committed this change, my file size drastically increased, exceeding GitHub's file size limit of 100MB. I'm starting to understand why this happened after researching, but I have yet to find out how to fix it. My git knowledge isn't the strongest, but any direction would be helpful.

Comment: use .gitignore file to ignore node_module folder(if not using .gitignore)

Comment: @IshwarChandra - Oh my gosh. That was it. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
node_modules/
```

to `.gitignore` file to ignore all directory `node_modules`